# "Contact Me" form that sends emails to me

Tags: python, html, django, email

I have the following HTML page:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'projects/style_contact.css' %}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text">Contact Me</div>

      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="input-data">
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
          </div>

          <div class="input-data">
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data">
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <input type="password" name="password"required placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="input-data textarea">
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <input type="text" name="message" required placeholder="Write your message">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row submit-btn">
          <div class="input-data">
            <div class="inner"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to send emails from that form. I know that all the Email configurations need to go inside the settings.py file, but how would i make sure that the legitimate owner of that email sends the message.
The form needs to get the correct password of that specific email address so that the legitimate owner is the only one who can actually send the message.
Any ideas??
Here is what i mean:
my email address is nn@nn.com (not really). I have a password too. My friends email address is n2@nn.com (no really). I do not have the password to that. How would i prevent me from sending an email through the Django form using my friends email. Because that is a security problem. Any ideas??

The settings.py file is:

```
    """
Django settings for src project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os



# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent #this was the original
# BASE_DIR =  os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-1!2hpx5ba$=lnvq#zu_98shz6@tj&uf#u0@pxh&tu+nm+l%5wr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


#Email Stuff 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '' # This is the 'from'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '' # This is the password of the 'from'





ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'projects',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'src.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Email settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

I guess my question is: Can i put the email configs in the views file?

Comment: should i include the views.py file??

Comment: show me settings.py file

Comment: i have uploaded the settings file

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
# Email settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
# EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

Add this instead

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'from@gmail.com' # this email will be used to send emails
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xyz' # host email password required
# now sign in with your host gmail account in your browser
# open following link and turn it ON
# https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
# otherwise you will get SMTPAuthenticationError at /contactus
# this process is required because google blocks apps authentication by default
EMAIL_RECEIVING_USER = ['to@gmail.com'] # email on which you will receive messages sent from website
```

Comment: did u turned on less seure in your browser

Comment: Thanks but i know how to do that. But then lets say i know your email address, i should not be able to email with your email address. Can you give me any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: did u get this error